# Axsis automatically changes to powers: eg. 4e+06, can this be changed to actual figure

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

Hi I am having an issue where the Y axis changes to figures in power rather than the actual figure, please could I have help on correcting this. Many Thanks

[Please see axis on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOWdW.png)

The code for the plot is below:

```
spendingARIMA <- arima(spendingSaas, order = c(1, 0, 1))
fianlforecastSpending <- forecast(spendingARIMA, h= 12)
autoplot.forecast(fianlforecastSpending, ylab="Sales in £", xlab="Years")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about "disabling the scientific" notation prior to plotting? like

```
options(scipen=999)
```